# Creating a string from multiple array values

Tags: php, arrays

```
if ( count($value) >= 3 ) {
    echo '<pre>'.print_r( array_slice($value, 0, -1) ,1).'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r( array_slice($value, -1) ,1).'</pre>';
}
```

... it prints the values as I expect, but I'm not sure how to convert it to a string so for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dr.
    [1] => John
    [2] => Appleseed
)
Array
(
    [0] => Jr
)
```

becomes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dr. John Appleseed
)
Array
(
    [0] => Jr
)
```

Comment: Or [`join($value)`](http://php.net/join).

Comment: Give a try to `implode(" ", $array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [implode()](http://php.net/implode)

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

// Empty string when using an empty array:
var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""

?>
```

Specific code

```
<?php

    echo '<pre>' . implode($value) . '</pre>'; // Dr. John Appleseed
    echo '<pre>' . $value[0] . '</pre>'; // Jr
```

Comment: You can simply use `implode($value)` instead